# Adding an empty object between each line in a typescript array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating an iterator with the .map() function like so:

```
var csv = this.invoices
  .map(x => ({
    invoiceId: x.invoiceId,
    invoiceDate: x.invoiceDate,
    invoiceType: x.invoiceType,
    amount: x.subtotal,
  }));
```

I'm going to be exporting this array to a CSV, and need to have a blank line between items.  The CSV helper doesn't do this, so how do I add in an empty object between each item in my csv array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to `flatMap` instead of `map`, and add an empty object to the front or back of the array, then pop or shift accordingly.

```
var csv = this.invoices
  .flatMap(x => [
    {},
    {
      invoiceId: x.invoiceId,
      invoiceDate: x.invoiceDate,
      invoiceType: x.invoiceType,
      amount: x.subtotal,
    }
  ]);
csv.shift();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: I like this! I'm embarrassed that my first thought was using iterators. ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols ) so that you're not creating yet another array, but while it would be better "in theory", simple beats clever every time!